# Are there any issues with missing this hand tendon?

Tags: tendons, hand

If I pinch my thumb and little finger together with my hand facing up and then roll my hand towards me, palm side up, I see a tendon 'pop' out of the centre of my wrist.

It appears only some of my friends have this tendon 'pop' out, though none have had surgery. What is it for? Is it there in everyone? Is it healthy that mine 'pops' out and theirs doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tendon is attached to palmaris longus muscles, a muscle that some people lack. There are absolutely no functional differences between people that have it and those who don't.

Check the wikipedia article for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmaris_longus_muscle

Comment: Thank you for this answer which is spot on (+1)! I was thinking: maybe it would be worth adding a picture of this tendon? Best regards. M.Arrowsmith